# Flip box issue on mobile

Tags: css

I've an issue with a flip box on Elementor Pro and I think you will able to fix it via CSS.

The flip box works fine on desktop since it flips when the cursor goes over it and it flips back once the cursor goes away.

Here's the issue: on mobile it works by "taps" and it only flips back once you tap anywhere else on the page. That's inconvenient and I would like to found a different solution, like flipping it back by doing a second tap on it (which is so much easier and intuitive imho).

That's every chunk of CSS that I've found inspecting the Elementor page.

```css
elementor-1370 .elementor-element.elementor-element-08b48bb .elementor-flip-box {
    height: 460px;
}

.elementor-flip-box--effect-flip .elementor-flip-box {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

elementor-flip-box {
    height: 280px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

On Wordpress.org I've also found this query about a flip box plugin: "FlipBox has no problem on DeskTops at Hover, BUT on my iPhone it doesn’t work at tap".

The fix was the following and, maybe, it will help.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.flipbox-content ,.eae-flip-box-front,.eae-flip-box-back{
cursor:pointer;
overflow: visible !important;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code. Or if your website is online, it's easier to take a look.

Comment: It's online, you can find the flip box here at example: https://www.origin-ale.it/web-design/